# Query in mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb

There is a database on mongodb. It contains a collection of `products`, which was created when importing from a csv file with a unique _id. In products, each document has a field `articul` corresponding to the article of the manufacturer. There is also a field `size` indicating the size of the product. Since the size of one product can be different, when you import documents are created which for the same articul will have different size.

How to make a selection from products and create another collection in which to put values with a unique `articul` that must contain all the values of size for each `articul`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). You can [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the documents on article names and [save](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) it in a different collection

```
db.products.aggregate(
{$group: {_id: '$articul', sizes: {$addToSet: '$size'}}},
{$out: 'articles'}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To store new size for existed articul

`db.products.update(
   { "articul": "Banana" },
   { $addToSet: { size: 9 } }
)`

if nothing matched from above query you need create new insert query

`db.products.insertOne({
   "articul": "Apple", "size": [8] 
});`